# Private member variable becomes null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, initialization

I have a class which looks like this in my Android app:

```
class MyButton {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    // constructors etc.

    private void aNonStaticMethod() {

        // code... 

        if (paint == null) {
            paint = new Paint();
            CrashReporter.report("paint null", "This should never happen, but it does");
        }

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(mColor);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(DEFAULT_STROKE_WIDTH);

        // more code

    }
}
```

The bizar thing is that the member variable "paint" actually becomes null once in a while. Previously I had some strange crashes, now I just have these logs in my crash reporter.

- [I have searched for the usage of the variable and the only place it is assigned is indeed inside the null check.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NO1y.jpg)
- [You can find the entire class here, where the variable is called "sPaint" (it was static initially).](https://github.com/bottiger/SoundWaves/blob/cf9efaecd98e5e673ec950657833dba22bc25183/app/src/main/java/org/bottiger/podcast/views/FeedViewQueueButton.java)

Previously "paint" was declared as "static final", but I had to remove "final" it in order to assign it again inside the null check. Static was removed a long time ago, and the problem still happened when it was "final".

In my career I have previously seen strange issues with the initialization order when dealing with static methods and variables, but since nothing is static and it's never assigned I am completely clueless about what could be going on.

My only guess is something along the lines: my method is called from some overloaded layout methods.

```
@Override
public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
    init();
}
```

Is it possible, using reflection or something similar, to find and call a method before the class is initialized?

and at last: Yes, the code is indeed very old, ugly and could probably use a complete rewrite, but that doesn't make a problem less strange :)

Comment: Who calls `aNonStaticMethod`? Is it always called from the same class (MyButton), as implied by its private access?

Comment: where are you calling this method?

Comment: Could something go wrong in the `Paint` constructor?

Comment: It looks like another method is setting the paint object to null... check that or post more code...

Comment: To all of you: Both the method and variable are indeed private and not called outside the class. See the source code yourself (or the screenshot I attached). It is only used 10 places, all very easy to understand. Nothing complicated is going on. I have no idea if the Paint constructor could fail, but it's not documented.

Comment: @bottiger I looked at the code. The actual private method (called `init`) is called by other methods within your class. Some of them override methods of the super class. If any of them is called by a constructor of the super class, that would explain why the member is not yet initialized.

Comment: @Eran They could very well be called by the constructor in the super class. How can I make sure to initialize the "Paint" variable then (if at all).

Comment: @bottiger perhaps your `init` method shouldn't be called from all the places it is currently called from.

Comment: @Eran Right, but that sound like rewriting a lot of code :) I'm going to double check that your hypothesis makes sense, and if that's the case I will just remove the crash logging since I believe the code works as intended. The "paint" variable  is checked an initialized in any case after all - albeit in an ugly way.

Comment: @bottiger Note that if you keep that ugly workaround, the paint variable will be assigned again once the current class is initialized. But since you'll be calling `init` again in your constructor, it will end up in the same state as the original Paint instance, so perhaps everything will work.

Comment: @Eran Right. If you can make an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual "aNonStaticMethod" (as can be seen in the linked code, where it is named `init` - BTW, you should include all the relevant actual code in the body of the question), is called by multiple methods in your class. Some off these methods override method of the super class. If any of these overridden methods is called by a super class constructor, your method will be called before the instance variables of your class are initialized, which explains why your member is still `null`.

A good solution would be to avoid calling that method in overridden methods.